# Find two Binary Tree are structurally identical

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree, jaas

I was recently asked in the interview

What would be the efficient algorithm to find if two given binary trees are structurally identical but not the content?

```
  a 
/   \
b    c
      \ 
       e

  z 
/   \
u    v
      \ 
       t
```

are structurally identical.

Next question was find out if 2 binary tree are structurally mirror ?

Any pointer or help are appreciated.

My attempt was

```
boolean isStrucutrallyIdentitical(BinaryNode root1, BinayNode root2)  {  
   if(root1==null && root2==null) return true;
   if(root1==null || root2==null) return false;
   if(root1!=null && roo2!=null) return true; // instead of value just check if its null or not 
   return isStrucutrallyIdentitical(root1.getLeft(), root2.getLeft()) &&  isStrucutrallyIdentitical(root1.getRight(), root2.getRight()); 
}
```

Comment: where is your attempt?

Comment: Hi Mitch, I have updated the question with my attempt.

Comment: I don't know that there's a particularly *best* way, but I would probably pick a traversal order (pre-, post-, or in-order) to use to convert the tree into a string of characters representing how many children each node has (so, e.g. 0211 in your example with an in-order traversal), and then compare the strings. Identical structure will result in identical strings. The mirror case is a bit harder, but I suspect if you use an in-order traversal, that might exhibit a reversed string in the mirrored case.

Comment: @plzdontkillme actually you were pretty close. for a starter your second and third `if`s are identical (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws). for the rest - try to take piece of paper and pen and draw some trees and try to manually "execute" your code.

Comment: @twalberg this is overcomplication.

Comment: @Andrey Not necessarily, as that is essentially what the example code is doing, without actually storing the string... The example code is an optimized version of my suggestion...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public boolean areStructuralySame(TreeNode<Integer> tree1, TreeNode<Integer> tree2) {
    if(tree1 == null && tree2 == null) {
        return true;
    }
    if(tree1 == null || tree2 == null) {
        return false;
    } else return (areStructuralySame(tree1.getLeft(), tree2.getLeft()) && areStructuralySame(tree1.getRight(), tree2.getRight()));

}
```

This works fine

Answer (score 0):

```
private static boolean compare(TNode curRoot, TNode newRoot) {
    if (curRoot == null && newRoot == null) {
        return true;
    } else if ((curRoot == null && newRoot != null) || (curRoot != null && newRoot == null))
        return false;
    else {
        if (compare(curRoot.left, newRoot.left) && compare(curRoot.right, newRoot.right))
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```